# Was Atiyah's proof of the odd order (Feit-Thompson) theorem false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups, k-theory

I read last year that Atiyah thought he had found a proof of the odd order theorem of only 12 pages, using $K$-theory, and that people were trying to figure out if it was correct or not. But I never heard about it afterwards.
Did people actually go through it? Was it correct or not?

Comment: Is that the Feit-Thompson theorem: every group of odd order is solvable?

Comment: Yes! I edited the question

Comment: As far as I can tell, it has neither been published, nor put on a public website (such as arxiv).

Comment: MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273828/what-is-atiyahs-topological-formulation-of-the-odd-order-theorem

Comment: I was in Heidelberg 2017 where Atiyah was circulating a proof of FT, but reading it with other people we found at least one mistake. I don't recall it involving any K theory, but perhaps my memory fails me.